# Can't access Linux (Manjaro) after Windows update

Tags: linux, windows, grub2, dualboot

My Windows decided to update today.
After it finished I couldn't get anymore into my Manjaro.
I can't access the GRUB Bootloader OR the System Setup Menu (F2).

Simply put, when I restart my PC (Asus X550VB), it blackscreens for a minute or two before I'm greeted with the Windows logo and asked for my Windows pin.

I can't get to the Boot menu or the Setup menu by pressing F2 on startup or pressing Shift then restarting.
When I do the latter it just blackscreens forever and I have to restart again.

I tried enabling Fast boot then disabling it again but it didn't work.
What do you suggest I try next?

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add that windows may have just changed the boot order in the bios.

this can be rectified by booting into live Linux drive and running `efibootmgr` and changing the boot order.

1. [reference to this problem.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/242219/435765)
2. [boot sector overwritten.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/68587/435765)

`pressing Shift then restarting` this in the most part just work.

[following this may help](https://www.asus.com/support/FAQ/1013015/)

As you have mentioned you are unable to access the bios through common procedures i would reluctantly suggest to disconnect the drive the all partitions are stored on and go into the bios and change some boot orders preferences to boot to live usb with hard drive connected afterwards.

Comment: I had the same problem recently and fixed it by disabling the fast boot option in Windows, so my guess is the problem is somewhere within the Windows again. I will try to boot to a live version though and check the partitions.

Comment: Laptop without the battery shouldn't cause any problem as power delivery is controlled by the hardware side,maybe some code in the windows upgrades that causes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by disconnecting all hardware from my laptop and restarting which brought me to the GRUB Bootloader menu. I am using a laptop without a battery and this is probably what caused this behavior, although i wasn't getting anything like it before.